# Creating Folder using Core Service maintaining path of source location

Tags: core-service

I'm using the Tridion Core Service to create new folders whilst trying to keep the same structure.

I have the following code:

```
using (CoreServiceClient client = new CoreServiceClient("basicHttp"))
{
FolderData folderData = (FolderData)client.Read(folderId, new ReadOptions());

string currentFolderId = string.Empty;
currentFolderId = folderData.LocationInfo.OrganizationalItem.IdRef;

// Create a folder in new publicaiton
FolderData newFolderData = new FolderData();
newFolderData.Id = "tcm:0-0-0";
newFolderData.Title = folderData.Title;

// Setup metadata, only applies if exists
newFolderData.MetadataSchema = new LinkToSchemaData
{
    IdRef = folderData.MetadataSchema.IdRef.Replace("363", "419") // This changes the tcm Id from tcm:0-363-1 to tcm:0-419-1 i.e. my target publication
};

// Setup location
newFolderData.LocationInfo = new LocationInfo
{
    OrganizationalItem = new LinkToOrganizationalItemData
    {
        IdRef = folderData.LocationInfo.OrganizationalItem.IdRef.Replace(currentFolderId, "tcm:344-16287-2")
    }
};

// Apply old metadata to new folder
newFolderData.Metadata = folderData.Metadata;

// Create the folder
try
{
    newFolderData = (FolderData)client.Create(newFolderData, new ReadOptions());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   // Catch exception here
}
}
```

My code works and the folders are created but the paths are wrong. For example in my source publication I have the following folder structure:

Content\Homepage\

Inside that I have three folders; One, Two and Three. When I run my code it doesn't keep this structure it just creates all of the folders under the the tcm Id of the folder I provide.

My question is, how can I do the above and keep the same folder structure? One thing that may be a problem is if the code tries to create a folder in a location where the "parent" folder it lives in hasn't been created yet.

Your thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create the child folders in the their respective parent folders - For example: Once Content\Homepage\ folder is getting created, you need to create Folders - One, Two and Three inside it.

To achieve it you may want to write a recursive function (or something like that of your choice) where you need to get the Path of the Folder created, do a sub-string for child folders and accordingly create.

You may want to write something like this:

```
private FolderData GetOrCreateFolder(string folderPath, SessionAwareCoreServiceClient client)
{
    ReadOptions readOptions = new ReadOptions();

    if (client.IsExistingObject(folderPath))
    {
        return client.Read(folderPath, readOptions) as FolderData;
    }
    else
    {
        int lastIdx = folderPath.LastIndexOf("/");
        string newFolder = folderPath.Substring(lastIdx + 1);
        string parentFolder = folderPath.Substring(0, lastIdx);
        FolderData parentFolderData = GetOrCreateFolder(parentFolder, client);
        FolderData newFolderData = client.GetDefaultData(ItemType.Folder, parentFolderData.Id) as FolderData;
        newFolderData.Title = newFolder;

        return client.Save(newFolderData, readOptions) as FolderData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pankaj. I'll give this a try and get back to you soon.